# How to rsync files older than x min on linux

Tags: linux, rsync

Here is what I have now:

```
rsync --remove-source-files -vr user@server:/foo/bar/in/ /some/local/path
```

Is there a way I can instruct rsync to only fetch files that are older than x min/hours from the remote host?

Here is some context as to why. The remote server which we don't have control over seems to be in the middle of writing a large file when our rsync job starts. Instead of an expected 200MB file we get something like a 40MB and corrupted file. From our end I figured we can control this if we only grab files that are sure to be finished.

Comment: You can run a find with ctime +<x minutes> and -exec rsync.

Comment: How do I pipe the results of find into rsync?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `find` to search for files older than x minutes and pipe the results to rsync.

`find /src/dir/ -cmin +30 -printf %P\\0 \ | rsync --files-from=- --from0 /src/dir/ /dst/dir/`

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87018/find-and-rysnc)

Comment: This will probably not work if the source is supposed to be a remote server.

Comment: If the source is remote server, you have to run the `find` there, too. Something like `ssh remoteserver find /src/dir/ ... | rsync --files-from=- --from0 user@removeserver:/src/dir/ /dst/dir` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

#Both volumes are local all files from 2 months ago (86400 min)

rsync -av --progress --files-from=<(find /Volumes/Stream/Video/ -cmin +86400) ./ /Volumes/Feb2021/

#If you want to go later than

rsync -av --progress --files-from=<(find /Volumes/Stream/Video/ -newermt 20210301) ./ /Volumes/Overflow